# Utilizar "assistir o" ou "assistir ao"?

Tags: ortografia

Tenho uma dúvida em relação ao uso da palavra assistir em uma frase. A seguir contém dois exemplos do uso dela:

> Vou assistir **o** filme.
>
> Vou assistir **ao** filme.

Qual é a forma correta das frases acima? Para saber se o uso é correto pode-se usar a mesma relação de "obrigado" e "obrigada"?

Answer (score 4):

No sentido de *assistir* que dás (estar presente, comparecer; ser testemunha/espectador), o argumento tema é objeto indireto. O *Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes* de Francisco Fernandes (45.ª ed.) tem isto a dizer (citações omitidas):

> **Assistir** *Relativo* — Estar presente, comparecer: "É como se o povo *assistisse a* um ofício divino." "*Assistir à* missa, *aos* ofícios divinos." "Não assisti ontem à reunião."

Há outros significados em que o verbo é transitivo direto:

> *Transitivo* — Acompanhar, principalmente em ato público na qualidade de ajudante ou assessor: "*Assistir* o ministro, bispo, governador." "*Assistia* o bispo no desempenho do seu cargo." **||** Socorrer, ajudar, proteger: "Enquanto conservou (Sansão) os cabelos *assistiu*-o Deus." "Sempre ficou com eles e os *assistirá* até o fim do mundo."

No sentido de de *acompanhar enfermo ou moribundo para lhe prestar conforto moral ou material*, Francisco Fernandes indica que ambas as regências são possíveis, embora modernamente a versão transitiva seja preferida.

Já agora, quando o objeto indireto não é uma pessoa, *lhe* não pode ser usado:

> Assisti ao filme.
>   Assisti a ele.
>   *Assisti-lhe.

Encontrei também [esta resposta](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/2242) na base de dados de dúvidas do FLiP, que descreve a situação no português americano assim:

> No português do Brasil, é possível encontrar usos deste verbo, neste sentido, como transitivo directo, pelo que a frase assistir o filme é muito frequente, apesar de não ser considerada preferencial por dicionários e gramáticas.

Comment: Informalmente, ouço dizerem e até mesmo digo, ocasionalmente, "assistir o filme". Já na língua escrita o verbo é sempre transitivo indireto quando tem esse significado: "assistir ao filme"